# Node form redirect based on submit button value

Tags: 7, forms

I've read and experimented with several ways to redirect a form once submitted. However, I only want to redirect a node form if the operation is t('Save').

If I set $form['#redirect'] = 'blah' in form_alter, it will redirect on all types of form submits. If I add a submit handler and then set $form_state['redirect'], this just gets overridden by drupal's node_form_submit.

What is the correct way to redirect a node submit only if the submit operation was say t('Save')?

NOTE: I found out that the generic form_alter attempt of $form['#redirect'] interferes with the node delete submit handler, as it has to redirect to node/%node/delete. So hence I am looking for a more accurate method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was to attach my submit handler to the submit button rather than the form, and then the $form_state['redirect'] would work as needed.

Comment: @zerolab you are correct, yet I am only allowed to do this after a certain time period ;)